# Заменить положительные элементы двумерного массива логарифмом максимального

Tags: c++

Написал вот такой код, последние две строчки массива не проверяет. В визуалке такая ошибка, не смог разобраться. [image: 1]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define m 3
#define n 5
int main()
{
    
    int i, j;
    float OD[m][n]{}, max = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {


        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "OD[" << i << "," << j << "]=";
            cin >> OD[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {

            if (OD[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = OD[i][j];
            }

        }
    }

    max = log(max); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {

            if (OD[i][j] > 0)
            {
                OD[i][j] = max;
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            cout << OD[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну неужели не приходит в голову, в чём может быть дело?  for (int i = 0; i < **n**; i++), и в других циклах попутано то так, то эдак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка очень конкретно описывает проблему. Индекс вне допустимых границ для массива. Дело в том, что в циклах `for` у Вас местами неправильно расставлены `m` и `n`. У вас один итератор должен бежать до `m`, второй до `n`. Только так. А у Вас они оба до `n` пробегают, вследствие чего идет обращение к несуществующим элементам.